# Spoon JAR for local testing

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, spoon

I'm trying to test making changes to the [Spoon source](https://github.com/square/spoon) (trying to learn how it all works) but can't figure out how to build the final jar (with dependencies similar to the one available from [the site](https://square.github.io/spoon/#download)) that we can then use to run independently.

I tried running the `./gradlew build` and `./gradlew install` with some minor code changes and everything builds successfully but I can't locate the JAR that works properly. :(

Any help / documentation related to the build/release process would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to add I build the JAR with ./gradlew build but when trying with that get an error `no main manifest attribute, in spoon-runner/build/libs/spoon-runner-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: How are you trying to use it? (please update the question, not just comment). I see the jar in ./spoon-runner/build/lib/spoon-runner-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar (it has over 11MB and all dependencies included inside, shadow jar style)

Answer (score 1):

1. Import project in **Intellij Idea** (not Android studio)

   - Import project from external model **Gradle**
   - `Next -> Finish`
2. Then you'll receive

> Error:SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Create `local.properties` file in root directory with following content:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/yourusername/Library/Android/sdk
```

If you see problems with gradle, press on gradle menu (tab at the right side) and click on synchronize/refresh button.

3. Open `Project Structure -> Modules`. Click `+` -> `Import module` -> `spoon-client` -> `Import module from external model Gradle` -> `Next` -> `Next`.
   Do the same procedure for `spoon-runner` and click `Apply`.
4. Open `Project Structure -> Artifacts`. Click `+` -> `JAR` -> `From modules with dependencies...`
   Select `spoon-client`, leave `Main class` empty, press `OK`.
   Do the same procedure for `spoon-runner`. Click `Apply` -> `OK`.
5. Click `Build` -> `Build Artifacts...` -> `All artifacts`.

`JAR`s will be created at the location you have specified in the `Artifacts` menu.

[image]

[image]